# TypeScript compiler produce "ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined" In IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Using IntelliJ (I guess it's also relevant for WebStorm).

Change TypeScript compiler to 2.1.4: 
Settings --> TypeScript -->Edit (Compiler Version) --> Selected the typescript/lib directory npm has installed

On the "TypeScript Compiler" Window got:

> Error:Cannot start compiler process:  ReferenceError: setTimeout is
>   not defined

When I try to compile in console using `tsc` I get a legit compilation errors.

How can I get those compilation errors also in IntelliJ "TypeScript Compiler" Window?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? TypeScript 2.1.* compiler is only supported since IDEA 2016.3.1

Comment: Indeed I'm using IDEA 15, Do you have a link to support that?

Comment: sorry, what link are you talking about?

Comment: How do you know Typescript 2.1 is supported only in IDEA 2016? could not find this information?
Also, is typescript 2.0 is supported in IDEA 15?

Comment: TypeScript 2.0 is supported since 2016.2 - see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/07/webstorm-2016-2/.

Comment: TypeScript 2.1 was released in November, 2016 - about a month ago. 2.0 - in September, 2016. The most recent update of Idea 15 (IDEA 15.0.6) was released on April 29th. Any more questions?

Comment: No, lena you made it very clear. Thanks for the info!
please answer my question (not in the comment) and i'll be happy to accept it so you can earn the credit for providing this valuable info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript 2.0 is supported only since Idea 2016.2
TypeScript 2.1 is supported only since Idea 2016.3.1